# Regex for multiple instances of character

Tags: java, regex, string

In Java, using a regular expression, how would I check a string to see if it had a correct amount of instances of a character.

For example take the string `hello.world.hello:world:`. How could this string be checked to see if it contained two instances of a `.` or two instances of a `:`?

I have tried

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[:]{2}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(hello.world.hello:world:);
m.find();
```

but that failed.

**Edit**

First I would like to say thank you for all the answers. I noticed a lot of the answers said something along the lines of "This means: `zero or more non-colons, followed by a single colon, followed by zero or more non-colons - matched exactly twice`". So if you were checking for 3 `:` in a string such as `Hello::World:` how would you do it?

Comment: If it is exactly one character, some loop test / count is rather simple.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina I am aware. I am just after a way of doing it with a regex

Comment: @Reimeus Yes as long as it is using a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex based on two lookaheads assertions:

```
^(?=(?:[^.]*\.){2}[^.]*$)(?=(?:[^:]*:){2}[^:]*$)
```

`(?=(?:[^.]*\.){2}[^.]*$)` makes sure there are exactly 2 DOTS and `(?=(?:[^:]*:){2}[^:]*$)` asserts that there are exactly 2 colons in input string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU6vM1/1)

Answer (score 3):

Well, using `matches` you could use:

```
"([^:]*:[^:]*){2}"
```

This means: "zero or more non-colons, followed by a single colon, followed by zero or more non-colons - matched exactly twice".

Using `find` is not as good, as there may be additional `:` and it will just ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine whether the string has exectly the given number of a certain character, say `':'`, by attempting to match it against a pattern of this form:

```
^(?:[^:]*[:]){2}[^:]*$
```

That says exactly two non-capturing groups consisting of any number (including zero) of characters other than `':'` followed by one colon, with the second group followed by any number of additional characters other than `':'`.